# Document class for a simple one-page assignment

Tags: margins, page-numbering, document-classes

I'm looking for a LaTeX document class which would fit a simple one-page assignment with mostly text. I'd still want sections and subsections like those in `article`, but would like:

- more vertical space
- no page numbering
- much smaller title, author name and date

Is there such a document class out there?

I tried to do this manually in an `article`. The title, author name and date can be solved using fancy header instead, and page numbering is easy to remove, but I can't remove the excessive vertical space on top and bottom. Also, such a solution would be worse from a re-usability viewpoint.

Comment: Have you tried using the `geometry` package?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no need to create a distinct class -- just load the [geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package and tweak the margin settings to your liking.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hscale=0.7,vscale=0.8]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Section **5.3 Body Size** of the [`geometry` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf)provides all the means to modify the layout of the document.