# Latex class for one page document

Tags: document-classes

Which class should I use to write simple documents?

With 'simple documents' I mean short documents (about one or two pages) without the indication of author, title and dates.

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Document_classes) that `minimal` class should be used for debugging purpose and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29571/document-class-for-a-simple-one-page-assignment) I haven't found an answer to my question.

Comment: Opinion based, but I prefer `article` for general work.  With the `geometry` package and an optional font package, it is quite versatile in its appearance.

Comment: `article` (don't use `minimal` unless you know what it does, and doesn't do)

Comment: article or scrartcl from the KOMA-bundle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default templates for the article document class commonly introduce the following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\section{}

\end{document}
```

The `\maketitle` command introduces the title, author, date components. If you do not want to have this structure you could just use the following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
YOUR TEXT
\end{document}
```

Then you can shape your document as you want (sections, alignment, margins etcetera).

Note, that there are many document classes that would allow for different settings, and of course that its not that difficult to make a document class yourself!

Comment: @BlackBrain, If you've a document with title only without author, you can also do so by leaving the field `\author{}` blank. **However** you may find large gap between the first section and the title, simply use : `\vspace*{1in}` or whatever distance you feel comfortable.